# Compiling OpenGL SOIL on Mac OS X

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures, soil

How would I link in or compile SOIL (http://lonesock.net/soil.html) into my C++ OpenGL project on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On newer versions of Mac OS X, such as Leopard, you'll have to edit the make file and add

```
'-arch 1386 -arch x86_64'
```

to the CXX macro of the Makefile. After compiling, you'll also have to link in the CoreFoundation.framework in your project. So your final build command might look something like

```
gcc -Wall -lSOIL -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -framework CoreFoundation
```

Comment: Is this when you compile SOIL or your program? Tried both but still get [file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked].

Comment: Should be `-arch i386 -arch x86_64` (note the *i* instead of *1*).

Answer (score 8):

There's a makefile in the zip that you could try using (projects/makefile). You'll want to rename makefile to __M__akefile (capital M), then just run make in the projects/makefile directory. You'll also need to create the folder for it to put the compiled objects into

From a command line prompt

```
cd <path to unpacked SOIL archive>
cd projects/makefile
cp makefile Makefile
mkdir obj
make
```

This builds fine on Linux, and should work on OS X provided you have a C compiler installed.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Luchjenbroers:
Actually you can just run `make -f makefile` and it will work (at least with my current version of make)

You can pass *any* file to make with the -f flag

Answer (score 0):

Clone https://github.com/DeVaukz/SOIL move to the downloaded directory.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```