# Issues linking SOIL through g++ in Yosemite

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, soil

I've been trying to link [SOIL](http://lonesock.net/soil.html) for a project I am working on with OpenGL. I'm running Yosemite 10.10.4.

When I try to use the SOIL library in my code, I get the following error (*updated*):

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libSOIL.a, 
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libSOIL.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_SOIL_load_image", referenced from:
  init() in main-93f615.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

**My Steps**

I followed the process indicated by the make file in SOIL: make, make install. It placed the libSOIL.a file in /usr/local/lib and SOIL.h in /usr/local/include. I included in my code:

```
#include "SOIL.h"

int width, height;
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("CrayonBox2.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
```

And my Makefile contained this g++ target:

```
g++ -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/opt/local/lib -lSOIL -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework CoreFoundation -o main main.cpp
```

Then the above error appeared.

I then tried a number of different things: I installed [this guy's version of SOIL for Mac OS](https://github.com/smibarber/libSOIL) (which places libSOIL.a and libSOIL.dylib in /opt/local/lib and SOIL.h in /opt/local/include); I tried adding `'-arch 1386 -arch x86_64'` [as per this answer's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884792/compiling-opengl-soil-on-mac-os-x). With each of these, I still receive the same error as before.

Any recommendations on what might be the issue?

Comment: Hi , have you fixed this problem ? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, what my solution is modify the makefile, to let gcc support 64 through add -m64.

also see Simple OpenGL Image Library/projects/makefile/makefile:

CXXFLAGS = -O2 -s -Wall -m64

Make install and replace libSOIL.a again.

I hope the answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the source files *before* the library specifications (`-l` and `-L`):

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include \
    -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/opt/local/lib -lSOIL -framework GLUT \
    -framework OpenGL -framework CoreFoundation
```

You probably want `-o myexe`, otherwise the output file will be `a.out`...

Comment: Thanks for that reminder. I had taken out the -o earlier because I thought it wasn't pertinent - I'll put it back in. This answer didn't fix it yet, but I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the pre-compiled static library.
Better to compile SOIL for your system. A pretty common compilation pipeline is using CMake and Make.
Clone https://github.com/DeVaukz/SOIL move to the downloaded directory.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```